# Python Azure function "Login timeout expired"

Tags: python, azure-functions, pyodbc

Created API's in python Azure function and Got "Login Timeout error" when Connecting to physical Database. I am using Pyodbc to Make connections with DB.

```
connection_string = f'DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};SERVER=tcp:{MSSQL_SERVER_FQDN};DATABASE={MSSQL_DATABASE_NAME};UID={MSSQL_DATABASE_USER};PWD={MSSQL_DATABASE_PASSWD}'
logger.debug(f'Connection string: "{connection_string}"')

conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

```
{"code": 400, "message": "[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)"}
```

Answer (score 0):

**One of the workaround I tried to connect with Azure SQL Server using the Azure Function (Python Stack).**

Make Sure you're using the correct connection string for ODBC and use it in the below code:

```
def  main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:    
logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.') 
error = ''   
try:   
with  pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:<yourservername>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=mySampleDatabase;Uid=azurekrish;Pwd=<YourPasswordHere>;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;')as  conn:  
with  conn.cursor() as  cursor:   
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO [ApplicationLogs] ([LogMessage],[CreateDate]) VALUES('This is a test log message 1.', GETDATE())") 
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM [ApplicationLogs]")
row = cursor.fetchall()   
except  Exception  as  e:    
error = str(e)   
return  func.HttpResponse(f"row fetch: {row}")
```

**Browser response for connecting Azure SQL and getting values:**

[image]

> "Login Timeout error" when Connecting to physical Database.

**The "Timeout expired" error commonly occurs when an instance of the SQL Server Database Engine is not running, when the server name was typed incorrectly, or when there are network problems or firewalls. Here are some causes of it: [Troubleshooting: Timeout Expired](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms190181(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).**